# Capistrano deployment asks for passphrase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, ssh, capistrano, puma

```
DEBUG [414156db] Command: ( export GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo"
GIT_SSH="/tmp/sunwoo-blog/git-ssh.sh" ; /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads    git@github.com:sunwooz/Sunwoo-Blog.git )
DEBUG [414156db]    Enter passphrase for key
```

I am asked to enter a passphrase when I try to deploy using capistrano to a DigitalOcean droplet, but I cannot enter the password.  I think I setup the SSH public/private keys correctly but I cannot seem to find a solution to this.

How do I make it so it does not ask for a passphrase when I deploy?

Answer (score 0):

The passphrase in question is the passphrase on your SSH key.

You can either use a key without one (risky), or use an SSH agent to only enter it once, and then have the agent handle it (recommended).

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I tried setting up ssh agent using: ```eval $(ssh-agent)``` and ```ssh-add``` on both my remote server and local session, but it seems to still require a passphrase.  It seems like it asks for the passphrase when I try to connect to github, is there anything else i should've done? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not installing your SSH private key on the server. The correct setup is to have your key on your local workstation with ssh-agent running. When you run Capistrano, it connects to your server using SSH with agent forwarding.

Assuming your key has already been added to the local agent, then the forwarding should take care of everything.

Answer (score 0):

This stumped me a few times but my issue was the SSH agent.

Check you've if you've got your key loaded in the SSH agent by running `ssh-add -l`

You should see something like:

`$ ssh-add -l
2048 af:ce:7e:c5:93:18:39:ff:54:20:7a:2d:ec:05:7c:a5 /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)`

If not, add your key:

`$ ssh-add`

Here's the documentation:
http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/authentication-and-authorisation/#